# Create menu link for authenticated user programatically

Tags: 8, routes

So here is what I've tried in custom module dir I've created `module.links.menu.yml` file here is code. I want to just for authenticated user beside Content link have my custom link to access Webform. Also, do I need routing file to?

```
description: "Link descr"
menu_name: main
parent: system.admin
url: 'internal:/admin/structure/webform'
  route_name: entity.webform.collection
title: "Webforms"
weight: -48
requirements:
      _role: 'authenticated'
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are simply moving a link of an *existing* route in a drupal menu, you are probably better off using the more simple [hook_menu_links_discovered_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_links_discovered_alter/8.2.x). A custom link/route is probably a bit of overkill.

But, presuming you do want to go the way you are in your example, you would need to have both a `my_module.routing.yml` and `my_module.links.menu.yml`

In the menu links file you might have something like:

```
my_module.hello_admin_user:
  title: 'Hello Admin User'
  description: 'See a Hello Admin User Message'
  parent: system.admin_config_development
  route_name: my_module.hello_user
  weight: 100
```

and in the routing file you might have:

```
my_module.hello_user:
  path: '/hello-user'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyModuleController::helloUser'
    _title_callback: 'Hello Admin User'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    _role: 'authenticated'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
```

You've got a bit of a mix going in your example. Note that route names and links names need to be unique across the drupal system. Using your module name as the start is a convention but not required.